# SQL Trigger for Insert and Update

Tags: sql-server, triggers

Sql newbie in need of help.

I have a table with an SQL trigger that occurs on Insert. It looks like this:

```
ALTER TRIGGER Holiday_ITrig
ON HolidayDate
FOR INSERT
AS
IF NOT EXISTS (
                SELECT
                        ID
                    FROM
                        WorkingDay w
                    INNER JOIN
                        inserted i ON
                            w.ID = I.WorkingDayId
                    WHERE
                        WorkingDayTypeId = 2
                )
BEGIN
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
END
```

However, I also need the trigger to fire on update. Is this possible within the same trigger or do I have to create a new 'update' trigger?

Comment: create new update  trigger....

Comment: Triggers run *once* no matter how many rows were affected. Is your trigger correct for a scenario where *some* rows match your `EXISTS` check and *some* rows do not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `UPDATE` to the list of actions.

You will need to check that the same logic applies to an UPDATE as well as the original INSERT.

```
ALTER TRIGGER Holiday_ITrig
ON HolidayDate
FOR INSERT, UPDATE
AS
IF NOT EXISTS (
                SELECT
                        ID
                    FROM
                        WorkingDay w
                    INNER JOIN
                        inserted i ON
                            w.ID = I.WorkingDayId
                    WHERE
                        WorkingDayTypeId = 2
                )
BEGIN
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
END
```

[CREATE TRIGGER MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx)