# SQL Trigger - After inserting a record update the balance

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables 
bracelets(IDbracelet,BALANCE) and MoneyLoad(IDMoneyLoad,IDbracelet,Value)
What I want to accomplish is to update the balance of the bracelet with the value of the MoneyLoad, everytime a value is inserted in the MoneyLoad table (balance=balance+value).

I am new to triggers so I don't know how to proceed.
Can someone please gimme me some insight on how I should do it

EDIT:
I tried the following but when I insert a record on MoneyLoad an error shows up saying the balance cannot have NULL values;

```
 if not exists (select 1 from Deleted) -- Insert Trigger
 BEGIN
        Update BRACELETS
    Set BALANCE = BALANCE + 
        (
        Select Sum(I.VALUE)
        From Inserted I 
        Where BRACELETS.IDBRACELET = I.IDBRACELET
        )
    From BRACELETS
END
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Trigger for Insert and Update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17143639/sql-trigger-for-insert-and-update)

Comment: Would you also want to update Bracelets when records from MoneyLoad are deleted or updated?

Comment: No,only inserted @DavidDubois

Comment: Your update statement is updating every row of Bracelets.  For any row of Bracelets that does not correspond to any row of Inserted, the SUM is NULL.  And so you are adding NULL to the existing balance, which results in NULL.

Comment: A view that calculates the balance would be a far better approach - especially for the very inexperienced. The computed balance value could be persisted if needed - but such decisions should be made at a later date. Implementation of triggers requires much more experience than you currently have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your trigger was trying to update every row of the Bracelets table.  For any row that was not included in the Insert, the SUM would be NULL.  Adding NULL to the Balance results in NULL.  You want to update only those records that are referenced by the inserted records.

Besides avoiding this issue with the NULLs, imagine that your Bracelets table has a million records.  Every time a record would be added to the MoneyLoad, all million records would be updated.

Also, the NOT EXISTS check would be unnecessary in an INSERT trigger. DELETED will always be empty.

This trigger may work well for INSERT, but you may want to consider what would happen if any records were updated or deleted.

```
create table Bracelets 
( IDBracelet nvarchar(30) not null primary key,
  Balance money not null default 0 );

create table MoneyLoad 
( IDBracelet nvarchar(30) not null 
  foreign key references Bracelets(IDBracelet),
  [Value] money not null );

go

create trigger tx_MoneyLoad on MoneyLoad 
for insert
as
begin
  if not exists (select 1 from Deleted) -- Insert Trigger
 BEGIN
        Update BRACELETS
    Set BALANCE = BALANCE + 
        (
        Select Sum(I.VALUE)
        From Inserted I 
        Where BRACELETS.IDBRACELET = I.IDBRACELET
        )
    where Bracelets.IDBracelet in ( select IDBracelet from Inserted )
END
end

go

insert into Bracelets ( IDBracelet ) values
( 'Bangle' ), ( 'Charm' ), ( 'Beaded' )

insert into MoneyLoad ( IDBracelet, [Value] ) values
( 'Bangle', 25 ), ( 'Charm', 10 ), ( 'Bangle', 20 )

select * from Bracelets
```

Result is:

```
IDBracelet                     Balance
------------------------------ ---------------------
Bangle                         45.00
Beaded                         0.00
Charm                          10.00
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding of your message error, I think that BALANCE can be a NULL value . Did you verify it (if your BALANCE has NULL as value for some IDBRACELET). If you are sure that your IDBRACELET is always filled; you can try this query :

```
Update BRACELETS
Set BALANCE = ISNULL(BALANCE,0)+ 
    (
    Select Sum(I.VALUE)
    From Inserted I 
    Where BRACELETS.IDBRACELET = I.IDBRACELET
    )
From BRACELETS
```

So If your IDBRACELET can be null, so you can try this one:

```
Update BRACELETS
Set BALANCE = ISNULL(BALANCE,0) + 
    ISNULL(
    Select Sum(I.VALUE)
    From Inserted I 
    Where BRACELETS.IDBRACELET = I.IDBRACELET
    ),0)
From BRACELETS
```

Hope this can help you.